# Why my form fields are not getting submitted?

Tags: javascript, forms

I used a ready made step by step wizard script but the form fields are not getting submitted. What could be the issue ? The JS is triggering fine in the end but its not fields are not showing.

http://avissoftware.com/wiz/

I tried adding jquery also but same result.

Any help would be appericiated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello could you please add code of your HTML part (the form and where you include the script file) and the JS part please?

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).  Please include all relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It's because you have two `<form>` elements. You probably want to delete the first one and change the `action="test.php"` of the second form that actually contains your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I noticed is that your submit/next buttons are outside the form and therefor not associated with the form. Also you have two forms.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Two forms solved for me. The js was already adding the form tag itself dynamically. I was not aware of that. I added mine also which was overriding it. Thanks for it.